# Snowflake: SQL compilation error: Invalid object type 'INTEGRATION' to grant privileges from

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a security integration for external_oauth in Snowflake.  I created it as an ACCOUNTADMIN.  I can see the integration when I run SHOW INTEGRATIONS. I can also describe it using DESC.  However, I can't GRANT USAGE ON the integration to a role and I can't GRANT OWNERSHIP to a different role.  For both of these grant statements, I get the error "SQL compilation error: Invalid object type 'INTEGRATION' to grant privileges from".

I have tried running it as ACCOUNTADMIN, SYSADMIN, SECURITYADMIN.  I don't understand why these two statements won't work:

```
GRANT OWNERSHIP ON INTEGRATION <integration name> TO ROLE SYSADMIN COPY CURRENT GRANTS;

GRANT USAGE ON INTEGRATION <integration name> TO ROLE <role name>;
```

Answer (score 0):

the [docs note](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-security-integration.html#usage-notes):

> Only account administrators (users with the ACCOUNTADMIN role) or a role with the global CREATE INTEGRATION privilege can execute this SQL command.

To own an object you have to be able to CREATE IT I assume..

but:

```
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;

create security integration external_oauth_azure_1 type = external_oauth
    enabled = false 
    external_oauth_type = azure
    external_oauth_issuer = '<AZURE_AD_ISSUER>'
    external_oauth_jws_keys_url = 'https::example.com'
    external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim = 'upn'
    external_oauth_snowflake_user_mapping_attribute = 'login_name';
```

```
GRANT CREATE INTEGRATION ON ACCOUNT TO ROLE SYSADMIN;
```

works, but still I cannot transfer ownership.

```
GRANT OWNERSHIP ON INTEGRATION external_oauth_azure_1 TO ROLE SYSADMIN COPY CURRENT GRANTS;
```

But swapping roles I can create one now as SYSAdmin:

```
use role SYSADMIN;

create security integration external_oauth_azure_2 type = external_oauth
    enabled = false 
    external_oauth_type = azure
    external_oauth_issuer = '<AZURE_AD_ISSUER2>'
    external_oauth_jws_keys_url = 'https::example.com'
    external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim = 'upn'
    external_oauth_snowflake_user_mapping_attribute = 'login_name';
```

I cannot see `external_oauth_azure_1` but I can show `external_oauth_azure_2`

Feels like the security model is a little incomplete, seems like a support issue to resolve might be in order.

Comment: Thank you!  I have submitted a support ticket with Snowflake.  I will let you know what they say.